# How to send a UDP-Pagakge via Android and AIR 3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, udp

i tried to send a udp-package via the datagrasocket-class in adobe air 3!
this worked fine as long as i test the app in flash-builder 4.5.

unfortunately if i test my app on the phone i cant send 
any package or better i can't see the sent package on the target-pc. (wireshark)

Does somebody know what goes wrong there !?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe Air has a new feature called [native extensions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) that allows you to call classes from the device and utilize them. You could simply use the mobile device's native UDP socket capabilities and I've checked that both [iOS](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) and [Android](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-udp-communication-example) have UDP capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Well i stumbled over the solution!

it is not possible to use DatagramSocket on mobile devices!

see: [AIR profiles](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS144092a96ffef7cc16ddeea2126bb46b82f-8000.html)

cu

Answer (score 1):

An interesting new library has recently surfaced in this area. Uses Native extensions. Looks to support iOS and Android at this time. Promising!

http://blog.aboutme.be/2011/12/14/udp-native-extension-for-air-mobile-now-with-android-support/